# set template_name on django ListView according to user data

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

my User model have a field which define there structure level in a firm.
my goal is to let each user to see his data plus extra data related to user under him.

I Have set groups permission to try and see if it would help me get what I want.
but permission is not really the point here
only redirect to different html( I want to handle logic in the back end )

on function base view this is straight foreword ( i think )

```
if request.user is *****
```

my problem is on class base view like this

```
class IndexHome(ListView):
    model = Task
    template_name = 'index.html'
```

I am not sure how can I access user in the class?

I know I can access the user from an instance self.request.user

but how can i make this work

```
class IndexHome(ListView):
    user = request.user
    if user.department_director.all():
        department_director = list(user.department_director.all())
        template_name = 'index1.html'
    elif user.group_leader.all():
        group_leader = list(user.group_leader.all())
        template_name = 'index2.html'
    elif user.team_leader.all():
        team_leader = list(user.team_leader.all())
        template_name = 'index3.html'
    elif user.tech_leader.all():
        tech_leader = list(user.tech_leader.all())
        template_name = 'index4.html'
    else:
        template_name = 'index5.html'
    model = Task
```

or maybe there is a way of setting template_name from the instance and my problem solved?

Answer (score 2):

As with anything that you want to do dynamically in a class-based view, you need to put this into a method. In this case the appropriate method to define is [`get_template_names`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/#django.views.generic.base.TemplateResponseMixin.get_template_names), which needs to return a tuple or list of template names.

The only other change is that you will need to refer to `self.request.user`, not just `user`.

Comment: thanks,  
so the hole logic of if self.request.user.xxx: should come in to my overwrite
get_template_names ?

Comment: OK it is working THANKS !!!  was voting your answer , how ever I am a new user ( less then 15 ) so my vote is not counted :(